# some questions regarding client ,server,API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, server, client

- Is it possible to create more API endpoints on servers to share a different set of user data?
  If yes, what type of user-specific Authorization can be used to protect these APIs (without adding any new admin API keys or another authorization method)?
- Is it possible to connect the client application to multiple Server applications? How?
- Is it possible to connect one more (or 2nd) client application to the Server for login?
  If yes, please list down the detailed steps for the changes you will have to make in the Server application to support multiple clients.
  Also, list down if any changes need to be made in the client applications.
- Is it possible to share complete data for few client applications and limited data for the rest of the application? How do you achieve this?
  e.g. client 1 only needs email & phone, but client 2 needs email, phone, birth date and address of the user.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes You can create more API endpoint, you can use JWT verification for each client Users.
- what is the purpose of multiple server application? can you elaborate more !
- As i mention in 1st answer, search more about 'jwt authentication in nodejs' for multiple users, so every user can use same API for login.
- Yes it's possible based on client's role, or if client/user don't have specific role, but client 1 need only email,phone and client 2 needs all the data. Then best solution is to implement 'GraphQL in nodejs' it will solve your problem